# Creating stored procedure with multiple temp tables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, macros, teradata, temp-tables

So I created a report that essentially runs a DML statement built off multiple volatile tables. The way I built it was that each of my temp tables would essentially derive off the prior.  For example, in my first table I define the 'dataset' while my other temp tables defining my "exclusions", then my last couple temp table combines it all and then executes it in a final query.

I want to automate this report to pull in data daily, but I'm not sure whether to create a macro or sp for it. The bigger problem with either approach, is how would I even be able to effectively utilize each temp table? I've thought about combining ALL of my tables into a GIANT (1000+ line) DML statement, but SURELY, surely there are better, easier options out there.

Any help is deeply appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Since you mentioned a daily data pull, you might not need temporary tables.  You might be able to use staging tables.  These are normal database tables which are not part of a normalized or star schema.  Their purpose is to help with the T part of an ETL process.  Instead of creating temp tables all the time, you simply replace the contents of your staging tables.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use global temporary tables. These are instantiated on access, are session local, and materialize in a users TEMP space instead of SPOOL. The table definitions are retained in the data dictionary, so you do not have to embed them in your overall SQL to build the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you could use `Common Table Expression (CTE)` instead of temp tables:

```
WITH cte1 AS
( 
    SELECT *
    FROM table_1
    WHERE
), cte2 AS
(
    SELECT...
    FROM cte2 
    JOIN ...
    WHERE
)
...
SELECT *
FROM cte_n;
```

One CTE can be depend on previous one or not, you could also use recursion and combine result in final query.

Comment: After much testing, I found the CTE to be the most applicable. However when creating a view from it, I'm not sure what the syntax is, code below:

CREATE RECURSIVE VIEW db.Test_View AS

WITH CTE 3 AS
(
SELECT
FROM CTE 2
),
CTE 2 AS
(
SELECT 
FROM CTE 1
JOIN ...
WHERE...
),
CTE 1 AS
(
SELECT
FROM ...
JOIN ON...
WHERE...
)
SELECT * FROM CTE3